# Establish the inequality for an analytic function.

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

So, I am self studying analysis. I came across this question. It asks us to establish the following inequality:

$\int_{-1}^{1} |f(x)|^2 dx \leq \frac{1}{2} \int_{0}^{2\pi} |f(e^{it})|^2 dt, $

for $f(z)$ analytic on the open unit disk and continuous on the closed unit disk.

My attempt: I have integrated $f(z) \overline{f(\overline{z})}$ along the upper semi-circle and have gotten the following:

$\int_{\gamma} f(z) \overline{f(\overline{z})}dz = \int_{-1}^{1} |f(x)|^2 dx + \int_{0}^{\pi} f(e^{it})\overline{f(e^{-it})}i e^{it}=0, $

by the residue theorem. Doing this again once more along the lower semi-circle with the proper parameterization for the circle portion gives me:

$\int_{\gamma} f(z) \overline{f(\overline{z})}dz = \int_{-1}^{1} |f(x)|^2 dx + \int_{2 \pi}^{\pi} f(e^{-it})\overline{f(e^{it})} (-i e^{-it})=0, $

Adding the two gives me:

$2 \int_{-1}^{1} |f(x)|^2 dx + \int_{0}^{\pi} f(e^{it})\overline{f(\overline{e^{it}})}i e^{it} + \int_{\pi}^{2 \pi} f(e^{-it})\overline{f(e^{it})} (i e^{-it}) = 0$
Taking modulus gives:

\begin{align*}
2 |\int_{-1}^{1} |f(x)|^2 dx| &\leq \int_{0}^{\pi} |f(e^{it})\overline{f(e^{-it})}| dt + \int_{\pi}^{2 \pi} |f(e^{-it})\overline{f(e^{it})}| dt \\
&\leq \int_{0}^{\pi} |f(e^{it})||f(e^{-it}))| dt + \int_{\pi}^{2 \pi} |f(e^{-it})||f(e^{it})| dt \\
&= \int_{0}^{2 \pi} |f(e^{-it})||f(e^{it})| dt
\end{align*}

But, how in the world do I finish it? If $|f(e^{-it})||f(e^{it})| = |f(e^{it})|^2.$ I would be done, but this doesn't seem true. Any hints would be great. Or maybe my approach is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea is first to treat the case when $f(x) \in \mathbb R, -1 \le x \le 1$ as then you can just integrate $f^2$ on the two closed paths formed by the real diameter and the two half-circles (upper/lower); technically to apply Cauchy, one actually integrates on the smaller disc of radius $r$ and by continuity take $r \to 1$

So on the upper path $\int_{-r}^{r}f^2(x)dx + i\int_0^{\pi}f^2(re^{i\theta})e^{i\theta}d\theta=0$, hence

$\int_{-r}^{r}f^2(x)dx \le \int_0^{\pi}|f(re^{i\theta})|^2d\theta$ and with $r \to 1$ we get

$\int_{-1}^{1}f^2(x)dx \le \int_0^{\pi}|f(e^{i\theta})|^2d\theta$ and adding the lower path inequality we are done in this case.

But now let $f(z)=g(z)+ih(z)$ the usual decomposition in analytic functions that are real on the real axis (the Taylor coefficients of $g$ are the real parts of the Taylor coefficients of $f$ etc).

$\int_{-1}^{1}|f(x)|^2dx=\int_{-1}^{1}g^2(x)dx+\int_{-1}^{1}h^2(x)dx$ since on the real axis $g,h$ are real

Applying the previous case one gets:

$2\int_{-1}^{1}|f(x)|^2dx \le \int_0^{2\pi}|g(e^{i\theta})|^2d\theta+\int_0^{2\pi}|h(e^{i\theta})|^2d\theta$

But note that $g(\bar z)=\bar g(z), h(\bar z)=\bar h(z)$ so

$|f(z)|^2=f(z)\bar f(z)=|g(z)|^2+|h(z)|^2+i(h(z)g(\bar z)-h(\bar z)g(z))$

But on the unit circle $h(z)g(\bar z)-h(\bar z)g(z)=h(e^{i\theta})g(e^{-i\theta})-h(e^{-i\theta})g(e^{i\theta})$ is clearly an odd function in $\theta$ and since by periodicity

$\int_0^{2\pi}(h(e^{i\theta})g(e^{-i\theta})-h(e^{-i\theta})g(e^{i\theta}))d\theta=\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}(h(e^{i\theta})g(e^{-i\theta})-h(e^{-i\theta})g(e^{i\theta}))d\theta$ it clearly vanishes being odd, so the result follows since we get that

$\int_0^{2\pi}|f(e^{i\theta})|^2d\theta=\int_0^{2\pi}|g^2(e^{i\theta})|d\theta+\int_0^{2\pi}|h^2(e^{i\theta})|d\theta$